# Tracking order status using FedEx

Tags: orders, order-status, shipment-tracking

I am right now researching on tracking order status of a product through FedEx.

I have a tracking number from fedEx with me of a real ordered item by a customer (*taken from main site*). I added that tracking number to my dummy ordered item after shipping in  my `localhost`.

I am getting the following error whenever I try to track a order from admin panel **or** from frontend as a logged in customer:

[image]

I think this is because of no fedex credentials inputted in admin panel. But I don't know where to add these fedex authentication credentials.

I tried adding the test credentials provided by fedEx in `System -> Configuration -> SALES: Shipping methods -> Fedex` but it seems no use. Still I get the same above error. (*FedEx also provided a test server, which is webservice, I don't know where to enter this.*)

Is it because I am testing it from localhost instead of main site? I can't test on main site due to other problems.

and also please give your valuable suggestions related to this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error with the test login is because your real tracking would/should not be accessible via the test login.

After doing some digging I found people suggest the following number for tracking ids that work with the fedex testing information:

1. 123456789012
2. 111111111111
3. 797843158299

The last of which is used multiple times in the official fedex documentation.